# How to add variable in existing class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I know that in swift we can use `Extensions` to add new methods to existing classes.

**But what about if i want to add a variable?**

```
extension UIViewController {

    var myVar = "xyz"
}
```

It gives like :

> Extensions must not contain stored properties

Comment: Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question

Comment: in an _extension_ you can add computed properties only – if you need a new property, _inheritance_ is also your friend.

Comment: Why downvote?, is it anything wrong?

Comment: @guru : Take a look at the answer posted below which shows the work around which is being used from years to add a stored property to extension both in Objective-C world and swift world :) Lemme know if its of any help\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't add the `stored properties` to `extensions` directly but we can have the `computed variables`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var myVar: String {
        return "xyz"
    }
}
```

> Extensions in Swift can:

- **Add computed instance properties and computed type properties**
- ...

For more please visit

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Answer (score 4):

You can only add computed properties to extensions as follows...

```
extension UIViewController {
   var someProperty = "xyz" : String {
      return "xyz"
   }
}
```

If you wish to use it the way you are defining it, you might need to subclass your `UIViewController`

```
class YourCustomViewController: UIViewController {
    var someProperty: String = "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can only use computed variables:
for example we have the type `Int` in swift, and we want it extend in a way that swift generates a random number from 0 to our number :

```
extension Int
{
    var arc4random : Int{
        if self > 0
        {return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt(self))))}

         else if self < 0
        {return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt(abs(self)))))}

        else
        {return 0}
    }
}
```

and usage :

```
myArray.count.arc4random
```

here my array.count is an `Int` , and `arc4random` is the computed variable we have defined in our extension, u cant store a value in it

Answer (score 3):

You can try ( This is a readOnly computed property )

```
extension UIViewController {

    var someProperty : String {

        return "xyz"
    }
}
```