# What is the correct method to add additional properties to CLLocation?

Tags: swift

I would like to expand `CLLocation` to store additional properties, however when I try to add properties to an extension:

```swift
extension CLLocation {
    let newProperty: Double 
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Extensions must not contain stored properties

I've looked for an answer, but couldn't find one.

Is there a way, and if so, what is the correct method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add variable in existing class in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972231/how-to-add-variable-in-existing-class-in-swift)

Comment: Create your own struct with a CLLocation property and as many other properties as you want. You can’t extend structs in the way that you want.

Comment: Since CLLocation is an NSObject you could add an associated object using the Objective-C runtime and expose that with a computed property, but I wouldn't recommend it except in very unusual circumstances. Better to use a struct that contains a location, or even subclass CLLocation.

Comment: @DuncanC Apple says "Use CLLocation objects as-is, and don’t subclass them." in their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation).

Comment: Fair enough. You **could** add an extension that uses associated objects to attach additional fields to the object, and then expose those fields via a computed property. However, that is a hack that depends on the Objective-C runtime, and might not be supported in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. What you need is to create a custom structure and add a location property `CLLocation` and whatever properties you need there:

```
struct Location {
    let location: CLLocation
    let newProperty: Double
}
```